# Problems in ipython %%timeit prompt

Tags: python

I am very confused with what is happening with `ipython %%timeit`.

```
In [1]: %%timeit for i in range(10):
    ....: print(i)
    ....: 
    ....: 
    ....: 
    ....:
```

It doesn't end the prompt even after several enters or even after pressing `Ctrl+C`.  Can someone share some thoughts what is happening here?  I am using Winpython.

Answer (score 0):

you may leave the %%timeit line empty:

```
%%timeit
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

When using a cell-magic (`%%` prefix, vs `%` for a line-magic), stuff after the magic word are arguments that can do various things. In the case of `timeit`, you gave it some setup code, with apparently some unexpected results:

> `timeit`
>
> Docstring: Time execution of a Python statement or expression
>
> Usage, in line mode:   `%timeit [-n<N> -r<R> [-t|-c] -q -p<P> -o] statement` or in cell mode:
>
> ```
> %%timeit [-n<N> -r<R> [-t|-c] -q -p<P> -o] setup_code
> code
> code...
> ```
>
> Time execution of a Python statement or expression using the `timeit` module.  This function can be used both as a line and cell magic:
>
> - In line mode you can time a single-line statement (though multiple   ones can be chained with using semicolons).
> - In cell mode, the statement in the first line is used as setup code   (executed but not timed) and the body of the cell is timed.  The cell body has access to any variables created in the setup code.

Apparently the magic processor didn't error out on a block fragment so maybe it would never end? Or maybe it did complete the setup code block without any visual indication, then was waiting for some code to time.

That said, for me (IPython 5.3.0 on Python 3.6.1), I get an expected syntax error:

```
In [1]: %%timeit for x in range(3):
   ...:     x*x
   ...: 
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    for x in range(3):
                      ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

What version of IPython are you using? It may be a bug that should be reported.